# Cannot load nvidia driver on Lenovo IdeaPad Y570 (Nvidia GT 555M)

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

So I understand that my laptop does not support Nvidia Optimus out of the box (http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work), therefore I decided to install Bumblebee, but it doesn't change anything, I get

```
joe@ubuntu:~$ optirun glxspheres
[ 4447.830749] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[ 4447.830844] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

So, I've tried the Bumblebee "hack" listed on https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/tree/hack-lenovo. I copied every line below into the terminal, is that what I was supposed to do? I'm a Linux noob.

```
git clone http://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch.git -b hack-lenovo
cd bbswitch
mkdir /usr/src/acpi-handle-hack-0.0.1
cp Makefile acpi-handle-hack.c /usr/src/acpi-handle-hack-0.0.1
cp dkms/acpi-handle-hack.conf /usr/src/acpi-handle-hack-0.0.1/dkms.conf
dkms add acpi-handle-hack/0.0.1
dkms build acpi-handle-hack/0.0.1
dkms install acpi-handle-hack/0.0.1
echo acpi-handle-hack | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

(had to use http:// instead of git://, in my uni).

How can I apply this "ACPI handle hack" on Ubuntu to solve my BIOS/Lenovo-specific problem and make Bumblebee/Nvidia work?

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/bbswitch/tree/hack-lenovo

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42696

> "Until this kernel bug is fixed, you need to apply an ugly hack on
>   these laptops to make bbswitch and the driver (both nouveau and
>   nvidia) work. For now I have decided not to put the hack in the
>   bbswitch module since it is a very ugly hack that is comparable to
>   writing a maximum allowable speed of 130 km/h on a traffic sign for a
>   road where 120 km/h is allowed just because the radar gun does not
>   work properly.
>
> The module has been tested on a Lenovo IdeaPad Y570 running an
>   up-to-date version of Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric (64-bit) with Bumblebee 3.0
>   (3.0-1~oneiricppa2) installed using the Nvidia driver."

It seems isn't fixed yet, so you must to try the dirty hack. I have the same notebook, and under Fedora I don't get work the secondary GPU (NVidia Geforce GT555M) because at boot system doesn't recognize VRAM or VBIOS.

Please try the hack from bbswitch or install bumblebee & bbswitch from the official repository and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on ubuntu, why not use the official bumblebee ppa and install it through apt?

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
#optional for newest nvidia drivers: remove #optional
#optional sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
#optional sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
reboot #important.
```

---

Bumblebee troubleshooting:

> #### [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: could not start X Server and/or Kernel oops with GT 600M series cards (Kepler)
>
> Make sure you have a recent kernel and the latest nvidia driver, i.e. not only the one, which first claims support for GT600M cards (302.17). First working driver for the tested card (GT620M - inside ASUS UX32) is the (beta) driver 304.22. (tested with kernelversion 3.4.6 on ArchLinux).
>
> To verify this issue, make sure bbswitch cannot be loaded (e.g. move it away) and try: "nvidia-xconfig -query-gpu-info".
>
> If you cannot solve your issue, continue at Reporting Issues.

https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Because that isn't enough. The Y570 uses slighty different IDs for the GPU or something, so it always spits out the same error as above.